# hasMany relation serialize:'ids' with EmbeddedRecordsMixin, how to "sidepush"?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, rails-activerecord

I am using DS.ActiveModelAdapter.

Saving a new Ember Data record to my backend, I would like to send :

```
{
    author: {
        name: 'Mike',
        book_ids: [null, null]
    },
    books: [
        {
            name: 'book1'
        },
        {
            name: 'book2'
        }
    ]
}
```

I thought it was what serialize: 'ids' was for, but when I use this configuration:

```
App.AuthorSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
   attrs: {
      books: {serialize: 'ids'}
   }
});
```

I just get :

```
{
    author: {
        name: 'Mike',
        book_ids: [null, null]
    }
}
```

***Update :***

The [doc](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html) says : "There is an option of not embedding JSON in the serialized payload by using serialize: 'ids'. If you do not want the relationship sent at all, you can use serialize: 'no'."

So it is not clear if only the ids are added or the ids and the records aside. I would like to have confirmation here that the records are not meant to be added aside by using serialize: 'ids', and in this case what can I do to "sidepush" nested records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like EmbeddedRecordsMixin was not the way to go..

Ember data Model Fragments was the perfect solution for me.
https://github.com/lytics/ember-data.model-fragments

Following the example I gave in my question, using the latter, the corresponding models would be :

```
App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  books: DS.hasManyFragments('book')
});

App.Book = DS.ModelFragment.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```